# Flask - cookies won't create

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

so i have two 'cookies' functions outside of routes to make code more organized

```
def get_cookie():
    # ip_address = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    ip_address = "X"
    access_token = os.environ.get('ipinfo_key')
    handler = ipinfo.getHandler(access_token=access_token)
    details = handler.getDetails(ip_address=ip_address)
    print(details.all)

    resp = make_response(render_template('base.html'))

    resp.set_cookie('ip',ip_address)
    
    app.logger.info("Creating cookies...")
    print(details.all['city'])
    print(details.all['postal'])
    print(details.all['latitude'])
    print(details.all['longitude'])
    resp.set_cookie('city',details.all['city'])
    resp.set_cookie('postal',details.all['postal'])
    resp.set_cookie('latitude',details.all['latitude'])
    resp.set_cookie('longitude',details.all['longitude'])
    app.logger.info("Cookies has been created.")
    return resp
```

```
def check_cookie():
    app.logger.info("Checking cookies...")
    if 'city' in request.cookies:
        app.logger.info("Cookies already exists.")
    else:
        app.logger.info("No cookie found.Creating new ones...")
        return get_cookie()
```

check_cookie() function check whether user have cookie named city and if don't triggers get_cookie() function

There's my simple main route.

```
@app.route('/')
def base():
    check_cookie()
    return render_template('base.html')
```

If i try to log my location info from API everything is going right but cookies aren't created... Any tips? ;/